# Upgrade Android Api Version

Tags: android

I have an Android device, apparently with API Level 10.

I'm developping an Android Application and I need to test it on API level 12.

I don't know much about Android and API levels, so my question is: Can I update my device to a higer API level ? (it says no New version available, aren't hier APIs considered new version?)

(I can't use the Emulators, as they really need a huge amount of ressources to start.)

Alternatively, is it possible to test the following code, on my API Level 10 device ?

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

I have the following warning:

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for questions in regards to coding, not broad issues.  To maybe get you started on the right track, you should look into installing custom ROMs that are specific to your device.  Sometimes those also allow for an improvement in the API version.

Comment: If it's okay, may I know why you need to test it on API level 12? Is it for testing purpose, or you need to use some methods with minimum API level of 12? If it's the latter, then perhaps we can try to give alternate solution.

Comment: android doesn't work that way. What you are asking is to upgrade your android OS which can be upgraded only if your device is supported i.e. has minimum required hardware. If you really wanna upgrade it, unofficially, then check forum.xda.com they have custom roms for many devices.

Comment: @antimo I need to test methods with minimum API level 12 related to USB service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes higher API levels = latest releases.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Version_history_by_API_level makes the correlation between API and version number (2.3.4).

You should work with a device supporting latest api and high resolution because many of your users might have that and you NEED as a developer to see and test your work on these platforms.

Get yourself a nexus phone, you can upgrade these to the latest Android version.

Android version release : Google releases it --> manufacturers and Telecom Carriers checks and adjust the release before making it available to you. Hence, for old phone, the manufacturers and carriers don't make the effort and you are stuck to old versions.

If you do no want to or if you cannot find a more recent handset, you can install a custom ROM  to try to reach API 12. But in any case, if you start developing, you ll need good handset soon.

good luck

Comment: This is not my final testing device, I just need to make a PoC before purchasing a new device (or not, depending on the PoC). Thanks for the answer, I'll check for the ROM for my device.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to see if there is a custom rom for your device that is of a higher api version. But this won't accurately test your app because there is probably a very good reason that a newer operating system was not made available for your device. As such, your app and the SDKs in the new API will probably not be able to make use of the hardware resources available, and you won't get an accurate representation of your app's performance.

You mentioned you can't use emulators but have you considered Genymotion's emulators? Although it is resource intensive it is better than Google's emulators and is faster than actual devices.

Comment: This is not my final testing device, I just need to make a PoC before buying a new device (or not). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using Eclipse ADT. You DONT have to update your device to level or API 12. All you have to do is specify the minimum required SDK, which is API 8 in most Eclipse ADT setups. and set your target SDK to API 12. That way your app will run on devices from API 8 through to API 12 Including you device. FYI the latest API is now 19 (Android 4.4) Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand. My device is API 10. My App requires API 12. So how can I set things up ?

Comment: Forgive me i didn't read the comments above when you mentioned your test methods required minimum level 12 API.